# JSON.NET(NewtonSoft.dll) changed my proxy class while updating my wcf service reference

Tags: c#, .net, json, wpf, wcf

I am working on HealthCare project. I have been given task to convert JSON format to HL7 format. To make it happen, I imported Newtonsoft.dll to my project. After adding the reference to my project, while updating the WCF service reference, I found my whole proxy class was changed because of the added Newtonsoft reference.

It comes up with more than 200 syntax issues in my WPF application. Most of the issues related to data type conversion, issues like:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.XmlElement' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

If I remove the Newtonsoft DLL and update the WCF service again, everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a type name conflict somewhere in your code. The Newtonsoft library contains a type with the same name as another type used by your source code. When you add the Newtonsoft library, your code gets confused over which type to use.

You can fix this by using the fully qualified type name (include the namespace).

e.g. If both libraries contain a class called XmlThingy:

change

```
var myXmlThing = new XmlThingy();
```

to

```
var myXmlThing = new ALibrary.Xml.XmlThingy();
```